# Why does na.rm=TRUE not work for weighted SD in R?

Tags: r, na, standard-deviation

I have a dataframe of 10 columns with house prices, that in some cases, includes NAs. 
I want to create a new column of `weighted sd` but for the rows that have a few NAs, I get the following error:

```
Error in e2[[j]] : subscript out of bounds
```

What I use per row (and works for rows without NAs):

```
weighted.sd(my.df[40,2:10], c(9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9), na.rm = TRUE)
```

**Example**

```
library(radiant.data)
data("mtcars")
mtcars[mtcars == 0] <- NA
weighted.sd(mtcars[18,1:11], c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11), na.rm = TRUE)#works
weighted.sd(mtcars[5,1:11], c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11), na.rm = TRUE)#issue here
```

What is the problem here and how can I create a new column with the weighted SD per row?

Comment: Please provide your data.frame `my.df`, output through `dput()`, or an otherwise [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of the error so we can better troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `weighted.sd()` will not operate as you are expecting across rows of a data frame.

Running `weighted.sd` we can see the code:

```r
weighted.sd <- function (x, wt, na.rm = TRUE) 
{
  if (na.rm) {
    x <- na.omit(x)
    wt <- na.omit(wt)
  }
  wt <- wt/sum(wt)
  wm <- weighted.mean(x, wt)
  sqrt(sum(wt * (x - wm)^2))
}
```

In your example, you are not feeding in a vector for `x`, but rather a single row of a data frame. Function `na.omit(x)` will remove that entire row, due to the `NA` values - not elements of the vector.

You can try to convert the row to a vector with `as.numeric()`, but that will fail for this function as well due to how `NA` is removed from `wt`.

It seems like something like this is probably what you want. Of course, you have to be careful that you are feeding in valid columns for `x`.

```r
weighted.sd2 <- function (x, wt, na.rm = TRUE) {

  x <- as.numeric(x)

  if (na.rm) {
    is_na <- is.na(x)

    x <- x[!is_na]
    wt <- wt[!is_na]
  }

  wt <- wt/sum(wt)
  wm <- weighted.mean(x, wt)
  sqrt(sum(wt * (x - wm)^2))
}
```

```r
weighted.sd2(mtcars[18,1:11], c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11), na.rm = TRUE)#works
# [1] 26.76086
weighted.sd2(mtcars[5,1:11], c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11), na.rm = TRUE)#issue here
# [1] 116.545
```

To apply this to all columns, you can use `apply()`.

```r
mtcars$weighted.sd <- apply(mtcars[,1:11], 1, weighted.sd2, wt = rep(11, 11))
```

```r
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb weighted.sd
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46 NA  1    4    4    52.61200
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02 NA  1    4    4    52.58011
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    37.06108
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1 NA    3    1    78.36300
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02 NA NA    3    2   116.54503
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Adam! The different weighted.sd seem to work for my data set. However, how can I populate a new column of weighted SD based on both of them?

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot that part. I added this in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a CTRL+click on `weigted.sd` function you can see the source code:

```
function (x, wt, na.rm = TRUE) 
{
  if (na.rm) {
    x <- na.omit(x)
    wt <- na.omit(wt)
  }
  wt <- wt/sum(wt)
  wm <- weighted.mean(x, wt)
  sqrt(sum(wt * (x - wm)^2))
}
```

When you run it, value vector contain values without NA's and it is reduced. But the weigth vector has the same length as before, resulting in an error.

A solution would be:

```
weighted.sd(mtcars[5,!is.na(mtcars[5,1:11])], 
c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11)[!is.na(mtcars[5,1:11])], na.rm = TRUE)
```

It's not elegant... But it does the job!

Comment: The function is actually dropping the entire (single) row of the data frame, not reducing the length of the vector. So it is not a mismatch between the length of `x` and `wt` as vectors. But yes, you can remove the `NA`s ahead of time.